# Jenkins maven Java heap space error

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am running a maven freestyle java job from Jenkins.

However i am started getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error suddenly in my console output and build fails.

I have multiple java maven jobs but this specific job failed.

I tried per job JVM options of increasing Xmx to 2048M.
Console output shows env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m when starting the job.

I also increased the maven global maven_opts property to -Xmx1024M but still it did not work. But it seems there is already an issue where global maven_opts does not work https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5409. So my only option is go with per job options.

My configuration : Maven 305, i run maven goal in my job using clean install -e -X . I am on Jenkins 2.60.3

Any other option i can try or am i missing anything ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: You must add configuration details of the project and Jenkins setup.

Comment: See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors

Comment: @user7294900...thanks for the reply..i am on freestyle maven project...i added -Xmx2048M in my project specific JVM options field...but still the same error

Comment: I don't know whether it's important or not, but the option should be -Xmx2048m rather than -Xmx2048M.

I had the same issue and the former did help.